# How to get order hash?

Tags: web3js, metamask, hash

I have an order in the form of a js object:

```
let order = {
    chainId: '56',
    exchangeAddress: '0x',
    makerAddress: wallet,
    takerAddress: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',       
    senderAddress: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    feeRecipientAddress: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    expirationTimeSeconds: '1640816586504',                                    
    salt: '123',
    makerAssetAmount: '60000000000000',
    takerAssetAmount: '1',
    makerAssetData: '0x...', 
    takerAssetData: '0x...', 
    makerFeeAssetData: '0x...',
    takerFeeAssetData: '0x...',
    makerFee: '0',
    takerFee: '0'
}
```

I have a hash of this order signed through the Metamask extension. Can I somehow repeat the signature of this object using the web3.js library to get a hash similar to the hash from the Metamask? Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of hash?

Comment: For what platform or application to you use this hash?

Comment: @MadeInDreams the hash that I get when I sign a message to the Metamask with my secret key. I would like to get such a hash programmatically, not through an extension. How to do this in js with such an object?

Comment: You might want to look at the message signing method.

Comment: @MadeInDreams hah, if I knew how to do it